# Linux -openldap 2.4.23 - can't see cn=config

Tags: linux, openldap

After fresh installation of OpenLdap 2.24.23 server on Linux, on LDAP Browser/viewers I can't see the directories like `ou=config, ou=schema`.

But I could see those present in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config`

**How can I bring up these structures?**

Reference: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html

On windows installation it shows up all these by default.

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable it in the configuration?

Comment: No I have n't. Could you please let know how to enable it. Many thanks.

Comment: See *man slapd-config*.